# Webcam image stream for website implementation

Tags: php, javascript, html, webcam

Setting up a live image stream on a website, using images from a webcam. Trying to work out the implementation of it. The webcam takes a picture and requires a crop, resize and upload (not necessarily in that order), before it is displayed to the user, with a new image every minute. Currently I have a php script that does the cropping and resizing, while a webcam program automates the picture taking and uploading. However...

Uploading directly over the existing image causes an issue if the user reloads the page while the upload is taking place, resulting in a missing image.

Uploading with a different filename, then renaming it causes an issue if the user reloads the page during the renaming, resulting in a combination of both images.

Using a sequential filename system then gets tricky with the webpage requiring to know the new upcoming file every minute, along with a potential backlog of images.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Hopefully I'm missing something simple. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why does your server respond with nothing or a combined image during upload/renaming?

Comment: The page is trying to display an image that has yet to finish uploading/renaming, ie an incomplete file, resulting in the issue.

Comment: But why does your server serve incomplete files? Shouldn't there be a semaphore that prevents reading during writing, and delays it until the file is complete?

Comment: Well for uploading, it doesn't serve the file, it returns an error for the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload your image with different name, set the current image name somewhere, either in config file or MySQL, and after upload change it.